# Shiny DataTables, adjust width or padding of one column

Tags: javascript, r, datatables, shiny

```
library(shiny)
runApp(list(
  ui = navbarPage(
    title = 'Tables',
    tabPanel('dataTableOutput', dataTableOutput('ex1')),
    tabPanel('tableOutput', tableOutput('ex2'))
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$ex1 <- renderDataTable(iris)
    output$ex2 <- renderTable(iris)
  }
))
```

What do I do if I want to make just the first column wider?

I "Inspect"ed the result, and found that what I really want is
[image: this]

this to change.
I know it has something to do with writing Javascript code, but the only other answer I found on here was if you wanted to change *every* column, and I don't know javascript enough to modify it without debugging. For reference, that code looked like this

```
output$ex1 <- renderDataTable(iris,
                                  option = list( drawCallback = I("function( settings ) {document.getElementById('ex1').style.width = '600px';}")) )
```

which is probably pretty close...?

if there's an easier way to do this without JS thats more than welcome!

edit: looks like adjusting "Width" in this way doesn't work on my actual data, but what does work is changing it from `style="width: 300px;"`
to
`style="width: 300px;padding-right: 200px;"`
so that's probably better...